# How can I MOVE, not copy all the files with the same extension?

Tags: windows-7

How can I MOVE, not copy all the files with the same extension from hundreds of sub directories into a single folder without overwriting same name files?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 7):

In DOS do:

`FOR /R "C:\MoveFromDirectory" "%i" IN (*.mp3) DO MOVE "%i" "C:\Move2Directory"`

Change the "MoveFromDirectory" to the directory you are searching in.  Change the *.mp3 to whatever file extension you need to.  Change Move2Directory do the location of where you are wanting to move them to.

Comment: I don't see how same-name files won't be overwritten, can you explain?

Comment: The MOVE command by default will not overwrite files without prompting when ran from a command line.  If you are using this in a Batch file you will need to add `/-Y` after the `DO MOVE`.  It will prompt you if you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 5):

Fairly easy with Powershell. This script grabs all the files with the .txt extension (from the current directory) and operates on each one: If the destination filename exists it appends the current timestamp (to the millisecond) to the destination filename.

```
$DestPath = "C:\NewFolder"


Get-ChildItem .\*.txt -recurse | foreach{

    if(Test-Path "$DestPath\$($_.Name)" -eq true)
    {
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination "$DestPath\$($_.BaseName)-$($(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssss"))$($_.Extension)"
    }

    else
    {
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination $DestPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you *really* want to move, use the `move-item` cmdlet instead of `copy-item`.

Answer (score 3):

Search all file's with a given extension, by entering something like *.exe in the upper right corner search bar of a windows explorer window. That will search for all .exe files in the current directory as well as sub-directories. At this point, all of those files will be listed in the window. You can now select them, and use cut/paste, rename them, or any other action you could perform normally in windows explorer.

Comment: But you can edit your question, which is preferable over an answer.

Comment: This isn't his question Patrick.

Comment: This is, in fact, the simplest method; if you only need to do it once.

Comment: This I believe only work in Win7+.